# Checking IsDaylightSavingTime against UTC

Tags: c#, datetime

I would want to check whether the time in UTC is summer or winter time. I am in the time zone +2 summer time and +1 winter time.

When I do `TimeZoneInfo.Utc.IsDaylightSavingTime(date)` it always return false. When I do `TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(date)`

It returns true, but at the date close to time zone change, I have the impression that it does it incorrectly.

For example date:

```
time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 02, 00, 01));
```

and this function return false for local time;

Is there a function prepared in c # for correct reading - it is summer / winter time for utc time?

My test for different times:

```
        List<DateTime> time = new List<DateTime>();
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 27, 23, 59, 59));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 00, 00, 00));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 00, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 01, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 02, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 03, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 10, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 22, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 23, 59, 59));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 29, 00, 00, 00));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 03, 29, 00, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 06, 29, 00, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 10, 29, 00, 00, 01));
        time.Add(new DateTime(2021, 11, 29, 00, 00, 01));
        foreach (var date in time)
        {
            if (TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(date))
                Console.WriteLine(date);
        }
```

which dont work when I change Local to Utc. And it doesn't work exactly right for Local.

Comment: UTC doesn't observe daylight and summer time. Maybe you need to rephrase your question?

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question. The UTC timezone, *by definition*, doesn't use Daylight Savings adjustments ever.

Comment: Every time zone may have summer time, and on different dates (on Southern hemisphere you have summer on different months). US and Europe use different days for the change. UTC is one timezone without summer time. But you should also consider where the data come from. You need to update your operating system or your time libraries, if you want the correct date (and if there is) summer time. We cannot predict the future (and some countries change rules just few weeks before the change).

Comment: You cannot determine daylight savings based purely on UTC.  You cannot even do so for longitude.  The east coast of Australia is [`UTC +10`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#/media/File:World_Time_Zones_Map.png) and during Summer _**no two cities**  can agree as to what the time is_.  Don't even get me started on `UTC+8`

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi thanks for information. I didn't know it was so complicated, I have to find another solution.

Comment: Your code works as expected for me. It includes `2021/03/28 2:00:01` in the output, if I replace `TimeZoneInfo.Local` with `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Australia/Sydney")`, since I am not in Australia. What actually is your local timezone?

Comment: @Sweeper gmt+2 poland. 2021/03/28 2:00:00. We were shifting the hands of the clock from 2:00:00 to 3:00:00. So the time of 2:00:01 did not exist on that day. Ok so it returns false for me. Now I understand.

Comment: Oh, I read MickyD's comment and thought you are asking about Australia, without realising that you didn't even say what timezone you were in! Haha. It returns `false` here because your date time's `Kind` is `Unspecified`. If it were `Local` instead, it would have thrown an exception because the date time is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I understood that in this way I was not able to correctly set the time. To solve my problem, I added a combo box with the downloaded system time zones and it projects the utc time to the selected zone, in which the Daylight Saving Time is already included.

In this way assign timeZones:

```
List<ComboBoxItem> listZone = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
foreach (TimeZoneInfo z in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
    listZone.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { Tag =z.Id, Content = z.DisplayName });
AllZone.ItemsSource = listZone;
```

And in this way change date:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var datetime1 = new DateTime(2021, 03, 28, 00, 00, 01, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var zone = ((ComboBoxItem)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem).Tag.ToString();
    TimeZoneInfo est = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(zone);
    DateLocal1.Text = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(datetime1, est).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
}
```